# getRecords not called on reference field change

Tags: lightning-web-components

In the first approach I have imported lat and long from object schema and refrenced it under wired function. This approach restricts deletion on those columns as it's referenced here. Although data and error is not consoled on every time boatId changes

```
import LONGITUDE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Boat__c.Geolocation__Longitude__s';
import LATITUDE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Boat__c.Geolocation__Latitude__s';
const BOAT_FIELDS = [LONGITUDE_FIELD, LATITUDE_FIELD];

@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$boatId', fields: BOAT_FIELDS})
  wiredRecord({ error, data }) {
    // Error handling
    console.log(data, error);
    if (data) {
      this.error = undefined;
      const longitude = data.fields.Geolocation__Longitude__s.value;
      const latitude = data.fields.Geolocation__Latitude__s.value;
      this.updateMap(longitude, latitude);
    } else if (error) {
      this.error = error;
      this.boatId = undefined;
      this.mapMarkers = [];
    }
  }
```

In this approach I'm using static fields typed in and hence it doesn't restrict deletion. I do get data and error consoled in this approach not sure Why above code is not working

```
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$boatId', fields: ['Boat__c.Id', 'Boat__c.Geolocation__Longitude__s', 'Boat__c.Geolocation__Latitude__s']})
  wiredRecord({ error, data }) {
    // Error handling
    console.log(data, error);
    if (data) {
      this.error = undefined;
      const longitude = data.fields.Geolocation__Longitude__s.value;
      const latitude = data.fields.Geolocation__Latitude__s.value;
      this.updateMap(longitude, latitude);
    } else if (error) {
      this.error = error;
      this.boatId = undefined;
      this.mapMarkers = [];
    }
  }
```

Comment: Per my understanding both approaches are correct. Maybe a different thing in your code?

Comment: Hi @AlbaRivas Looks like the first method doesn't support Geolocations fields like Geolocation__Longitude__s or Geolocation__Latitude__s. I saw this mentioned in their docs a little back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the first method doesn't support Geolocations fields like Geolocation__Longitude__s or Geolocation__Latitude__s. Used this approach and worked perfectly

```
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$boatId', fields: ['Boat__c.Id', 'Boat__c.Geolocation__Longitude__s', 'Boat__c.Geolocation__Latitude__s']})
  wiredRecord({ error, data }) {
    // Error handling
    console.log(data, error);
    if (data) {
      this.error = undefined;
      const longitude = data.fields.Geolocation__Longitude__s.value;
      const latitude = data.fields.Geolocation__Latitude__s.value;
      this.updateMap(longitude, latitude);
    } else if (error) {
      this.error = error;
      this.boatId = undefined;
      this.mapMarkers = [];
    }
  }
```